# Windows 10 remote tools not working, mmc, psexec etc

Tags: windows-10, rpc, netsh

I'm having a problems on the network
Some newer Windows 10 PC's (Win10 image from Dell), behave different, then older Dell PC's.
They have the same service pack's and hotfixes, its something in settings.

They don't accept remote administration tasks, such Manage PC by using an MMC to a remote \client
And neither do they accept Sysinternals remote tools like psexec etc.
I've noticed that those machines don't allow RPC connections.

Although those services run :

- RPC Endpoint Mapper
- DCOM Server Process Launcher
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

And i made sure the rpc is allowed

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RPC endpoint mapper" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=135
```

Any ideas of what this could be ?.

Comment: You're probably on the right track looking at local firewall rules. You can use wf.msc to view logs/rules and even temporarily disable filtering to rule it out.

Comment: right it was a combo error, GLPI didnt execute updated firewall rules to some clients (still investigating that). and so there were FW diffeerences in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a firewall rule problem. And a problem in remote tooling, GLPI didnt work on some clients.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RPC endpoint mapper" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=135 profile=Domain,Private remoteip=172.16.1.0/16,LocalSubnet
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="File and Printer Sharing (NB-Datagram-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=445 profile=Domain,Private remoteip=172.16.1.0/16,LocalSubnet
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="File and Printer Sharing (NB-Datagram-In)" new enable=yes profile=Domain,Private remoteip=172.16.1.0/16,LocalSubnet
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

also at least those services should run

```
Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
RPC Endpoint Mapper
DCOM Server Process Launcher
```

other people diving into it, you might alter the ipnumbers and masks to suit your site.